# Point src to self in image using html or php?

Tags: php, html

How can I make a src link to somehting ina  folder without adding in the current url of the page in hard code?

Example:

`<img src="/images/tomato.jpg" />` in the code should come out as:

`<img src="www.example.com/afolder/images/tomato.jpg" />` when viewed on the `www.example.com/afolder/index.html` page

Is it possible to do this with just HTML?  If not, is it possible with PHP?

Comment: What difference would this make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a path begins with `/`, it's relative to the root directory of the web site. If it does not begin with a `/`, the path is relative to the current page's path (unless you've overridden that with a `<base>` tag). So in your case, simply making the path not root relative by dropping the leading `/` will solve your problem.

```
<img src="images/tomato.jpg" />
```

Comment: This worked!  Removing the backslash.  Thank you for the explanation too.

Comment: ...and fail in every other folder.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: There was no mention at all of this markup being included in any other folder. There is no reason to assume that this appears on more than one page (eg. a header, footer, etc.). So there is no cause to clutter the code with unnecessary PHP when pure HTML solves the problem simply and elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `<img src="images/tomato.jpg" />`? Alternatively, you can set the [base href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="www.example.com/afolder/images/tomato.jpg" />` won't show you anything. `<img src="/afolder/images/tomato.jpg" />` you mean?

although it is possible in HTML, this way will affect every URL on the page, which may lead to **unpredicted** results.

So, the only sensible way is to add some PHP variable,

```
<img src="<?=$somefolder?>/images/tomato.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with html. (Although you could use the [html base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp), it doesn't do quite what you want.)

In PHP, you would do this:

```
define("BASE_IMAGE_URL", "www.example.com/afolder/");

<img src="<?= BASE_IMAGE_URL ?>images/tomato.jpg" />
```